# Trying to use cloudinary with requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd, cloudinary

I am trying to use cloudinary library using below code, but i keep on getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of undefined".

**main.js**

```
require.config({
  shim: {
    "jquery": {},
  }
});
require(['jquery', 'jquery.ui.widget', 'jquery.iframe-transport', 'jquery.fileupload', 'jquery.cloudinary'], function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.cloudinary.config({
      cloud_name: 'sample',
      api_key: '874837483274837'
    })
  });
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<script data-main="js/main.js" type="text/javascript" src="js/require.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you are missing a few shims here. You need to add the jQuery plugins as a shim which, in turn, have jQuery as a requirement: `shim: {'jquery.cloudinary': {   deps: ['jquery'] }}`. You should be doing that for all jQuery plugins you want to attach to `$` (or whichever symbol you define) in your RequireJS aware JS.

Comment: Tried,  still getting "Cannot read property 'config' of undefined"

Comment: did you include the `jquery.cloudinary.js` script in your `js/` folder?

Comment: A quick demo on http://jsfiddle.net would be very useful.

Comment: If this is truly you `main.js`, thus the only configuration you do, then it means you are lazy loading the JS libraries and not using any `paths`. As @Louy pointed out, please check that each file is there in your `js` directory, top level. It is also interesting to see what the network tab of your Firebug (or equivalent tool) tells you when in tries to load 'jquery.cloudinary.js' ... do you get a 404 on that file for example?

Comment: I have uploaded the code on my private server and below is the link.
http://apiworks.in/cloudinary/index.html.

All file seems to be loading perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Cloudinary widget `all.js` can't be loaded straight using require.js (even using [shim](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim)). We can only catch a moment of time when the script is loaded and get the widget object from `window`.

```
// Require.js doesn't load the Cloudinary script if it specified in a `required` call but does load if in a `define`
define('cloudinary', ['https://widget.cloudinary.com/global/all.js'], function () {
    return window.cloudinary;
});

require(['cloudinary'], function (cloudinary) {
    console.log(cloudinary);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Seems like they had some bug with the library, they fixed it with the version 2.0.4.

Comment: Does that mean you're not getting TypeErrors anymore, without change of code?